# applying licensing to Nexus 5k

Tags: cisco-nexus-5k, cisco-nexus

I'm running a pair of 5596Ts as a vPC pair. These make up the core in our DC, all L3 is handled here (daughter card installed), all subnet gateways live here, using HSRP across them all. Our current licensing is lan base. I have a project which requires the use of PBR, so I need to upgrade to N55_LAN1K9 licensing, which we have purchased for both switches.

What I cannot seem to get an answer on, is will I need to reload after I install the licensing? It seems that I can enable PBR (and other features) without dropping traffic or needing/causing a reload, but I can't find a definitive answer anywhere.

I've read through the licensing docs from Cisco but again I didn't see anything clearly stating yes or no. http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5000/sw/configuration/guide/cli/CLIConfigurationGuide/Licensing.html

On a similar note, can I safely assume that all features can be added without dropping traffic or otherwise impacting performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not need to reboot the switch!

Comment: Awesome. Can we take this a step further and verify that I will not impact traffic when I apply it?

Comment: For reference, no traffic was impacted during either the license installation or the feature additions.